# Android Studio Current Location Google Map

Tags: java, android, google-maps, gps, location

I am supposed when I open google maps in my application to have a direct focus on the current user's position.
With a lot of researches, I found the correct way to do it (avoiding as well all the deprecated functions) but I still can't find the right way to check my permissions. Here are my codes :

LocationProvider.class

```
public class LocationProvider implements
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener {

public abstract interface LocationCallback {
    public void handleNewLocation(Location location);


}

public static final String TAG = LocationProvider.class.getSimpleName();



/*
 * Define a request code to send to Google Play services
 * This code is returned in Activity.onActivityResult
 */
private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

private LocationCallback mLocationCallback;
private Context mContext;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

int 

public LocationProvider(Context context, LocationCallback callback) {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();

    mLocationCallback = callback;

    // Create the LocationRequest object
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
            .setInterval(10 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
            .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000); // 1 second, in milliseconds

    mContext = context;
}

public void connect() {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

public void disconnect() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Location services connected.");


    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)) {
        Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (location == null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        } else {
            mLocationCallback.handleNewLocation(location);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    /*
     * Google Play services can resolve some errors it detects.
     * If the error has a resolution, try sending an Intent to
     * start a Google Play services activity that can resolve
     * error.
     */
    if (connectionResult.hasResolution() && mContext instanceof Activity) {
        try {
            Activity activity = (Activity)mContext;
            // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
            connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(activity, CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
        /*
         * Thrown if Google Play services canceled the original
         * PendingIntent
         */
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            // Log the error
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        /*
         * If no resolution is available, display a dialog to the
         * user with the error.
         */
        Log.i(TAG, "Location services connection failed with code " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
    }
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mLocationCallback.handleNewLocation(location);
}
```

}

MapsActivity.class

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationProvider.LocationCallback {

public static final String TAG = MapsActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.

private LocationProvider mLocationProvider;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();


    mLocationProvider = new LocationProvider(this, this);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
    mLocationProvider.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mLocationProvider.disconnect();
}

/**
 * Sets up the map if it is possible to do so (i.e., the Google Play services APK is correctly
 * installed) and the map has not already been instantiated.. This will ensure that we only ever
 * call {@link #setUpMap()} once when {@link #mMap} is not null.
 * <p/>
 * If it isn't installed {@link SupportMapFragment} (and
 * {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView MapView}) will show a prompt for the user to
 * install/update the Google Play services APK on their device.
 * <p/>
 * A user can return to this FragmentActivity after following the prompt and correctly
 * installing/updating/enabling the Google Play services. Since the FragmentActivity may not
 * have been completely destroyed during this process (it is likely that it would only be
 * stopped or paused), {@link #onCreate(Bundle)} may not be called again so we should call this
 * method in {@link #onResume()} to guarantee that it will be called.
 */
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case, we
 * just add a marker near Africa.
 * <p/>
 * This should only be called once and when we are sure that {@link #mMap} is not null.
 */
private void setUpMap() {
    //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
}

public void handleNewLocation(Location location) {
    Log.d(TAG, location.toString());

    double currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    double currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);

    //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude)).title("Current Location"));
    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
            .position(latLng)
            .title("I am here!");
    mMap.addMarker(options);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
}
```

}

I tried to check the permission here but my activity isn't recognized :

```
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MapsActivity,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)) {
    Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (location == null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    } else {
        mLocationCallback.handleNewLocation(location);
    }
}
```

The goal is simple though, just opening google maps with my current gps position at the center. But all resources and forums are obsolete.

Thanks a lot for your help !!

Comment: https://github.com/treehouse/android-location-example/blob/master/app/src/main/java/teamtreehouse/com/iamhere/MapsActivity.java

Comment: The code needs to check for permission to execute these lines for me.